# Understanding sufficient properties of a filter base

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be an arbitrary set and $\mathscr{A}$ a set of its subsets.  Then the following is sufficient (Treves, 1995) for $\mathscr{A}$ to be a (proper) filter base in $E$:

1. $\emptyset\notin\mathscr{A}$
2. The intersection of any two members of $\mathscr{A}$ contains a member of $\mathscr{A}$.

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the filter generated by $\mathscr{A}$, and let $F = F_1\cap{F_2}$ where $F_1, F_2\in\mathscr{F}$. Then $F\in\mathscr{F}$ by definition, since intersections of members of a filter belong to the filter. Furthermore, since $\mathscr{F}$ has $\mathscr{A}$ as its base, $F$ must contain a member of $\mathscr{A}$.

I maintain that $F$ need not contain a member of $\mathscr{A}$, since the fact that $F_1$ and $F_2$ individually contain members of $\mathscr{A}$ - say, $A_1$ and $A_2$, respectively -  need not mean that $F$ contains $A_1\cap{A_2}$ in particular, nor any member of $\mathscr{A}$ in general.  Thus, $\mathscr{A}$ meets the sufficiency conditions but is **not** a filter base for $\mathscr{F}$.

Why am I wrong?

Comment: It seems you do not agree with: If $A_1\subseteq F_1$ and $A_2\subseteq F_2$ and  $A\subseteq A_1\cap A_2$, then $A\subseteq F_1\cap F_2$?

Comment: If $F_1$ (resp. $F_2$) contains $A_1$ (resp. $A_2$), then $$A_1\cap A_2\subseteq F_1\cap F_2$$ Its a general property of intersection. Then, by the second condition there is $\mathscr A\ni A_3\subseteq A_1\cap A_2$ and so $F=F_1\cap F_2$ contains a member of $\mathscr A$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've been assuming that $A_1\cap{A_2}=\emptyset$ and that empty intersections are allowed. That might be the flaw in my reading!

Comment: @Alessandro But my hypothesis is that $A_1$ and $A_2$ do not intersect.  Of course, if the empty intersection is included in the definition then I am not allowed to assume that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and Alessandro, is the underlying premise that (in general) *all subsets of a set intersect*?   Some of those intersections are empty and others are not, but the intersection always exists?  With that, it makes sense.

Comment: Two elements in $\mathscr A$ cannot have empty intersection because then by property 2) there is an element of $\mathscr A$ contained in the intersection, so there is an element of $\mathscr A$ contained in (and thus equal to) $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, contrary to property 1) that $\emptyset\notin\mathscr A$

Answer (score 0):

I am wrong because I have taken two sets having an "empty intersection" to mean that they have no intersection. In fact, two sets having an "empty intersection" have the empty set - which is a set in the true sense of the word - as their intersection.  Since this set may not be part of a filter base, any two members of a filter base have a non-empty set as their intersection.

Comment: The question demonstrates a flaw in reasoning, which has been manifested and removed through the answer. I'm assuming this is a mistake others may make, and is therefore of value to demonstrate and address.

Comment: I still think you should have asked one the two users hand-holding you, to answer.  Or perhaps make this Community Wiki, and add credit to those who helped you understand your mistake, within the post.

Comment: Handholding.. you sound lovely. Anyhow, my answer points are zero, so hopefully you'll find that reassuring in terms of my not accruing false reputation for my maths and stats degrees.